# Npm build error on jenkins node-sass/vendor

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jenkins, npm, next.js

I am trying `npm build` using Jenkins on the server. It throws me the same error always.

```
info  - Using external babel configuration from /opt/jenkins/workspace/i-frontend-ui_jenkin_buildBranch/.babelrc
Failed to compile.
./pages/app.scss
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/opt/jenkins/workspace/i-frontend-ui_jenkin_buildBranch/node_modules/node-sass/vendor'
> Build error occurred
Error: > Build failed because of webpack errors
    at build (/opt/jenkins/workspace/i-frontend-ui_jenkin_buildBranch/node_modules/next/dist/build/index.js:15:918)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! siem-analytics@1.0.0-jenkinbuildbranch.0cb23412 build: `next build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the siem-analytics@1.0.0-jenkinbuildbranch.0cb23412 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

If I try to do  `npm build` on local it works.

node and npm version on local
`node: v12.18.1`
`npm : 6.7.0`

version on server
`node: v12.16.3`
`npm : 6.14.4`

Any idea of how to fix this? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks In advance

Comment: Try to rebuild node-sass      npm rebuild node-sass

Comment: I tried it many times. Any other solution